# why express send a JSESESSIONID to the browser as a cookie while not specified?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies, jsessionid

I am trying to implement a solution to `csrf` attacks on a signup form so I wanted to use the session id as the text to be signed with the secret key then hashed with sha512 with hmac to be send in a cookie and form hidden input for future validations when submitting , however i found an error that `req.session` is undefined .

here is the problem how is it undefined given that google chrome inspect reveals that there is a cookie named `JSESESSIONID` sent from my app to the browser with a very big value .

so my questions are:

1- what is this session ( `JSESESSIONID` ) ?

2- why nodejs express send this token in a cookie in the first place given that i didn't specify that ?

3- is it suitable to use this session token as my hmac value or no ?

I searched all stackoverflow but no one says anything about this token in nodejs and express. so i would be glad to find an answer here.

**UPDATE:**

this is my app.js where you can see my middelwares ( i don't use the session var )

```
//var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
//var csrf = require('csurf');
var logger = require('morgan');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/Ahmeed/Desktop/front/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/Ahmeed/Desktop/front/server.cert', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var signupRouter = require('./routes/signup.js');
var verificationRouter = require('./routes/verify.js');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login.js');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/signup', signupRouter);
app.use('/verify', verificationRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);




var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server started listening on port 3000");
});

module.exports = app;
```

and this part of my login router

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var session = req.session;
  console.log(session);
  var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', 'ABCD').update(session).digest('hex');
  res.cookie( 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', hash,{ maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10, httpOnly: true });
  res.render('signup', { title: 'signup section' });
});
```

Comment: Your express server probably has some session-handling middleware doing this. Look for calls to `app.use()` in your server initialization, and see if you can spot some middleware for this purpose. Absolutely do not use a token like this for any kind of security purpose unless you understand *exactly* where it comes from.

Comment: @O.Jones yes thats why i ask what it is before i see if i can use it ,,, see my updates i added my app.use

Comment: Take a look at your login router. It may be feeding that cookie to your browser.

Comment: @O.Jones i added it to question i dont see any error in the cookie itself but i see the error in the hmac function that say that the provided session parameter is undefined